# asp.net mvc 3 view looping through model with foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, foreach

I am having a view with tied to a model:

```
@model IEnumerable<AJA.Models.DB.Article>
```

all I want to do is to loop through the model to do some logic:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var article = item.article1;
    if (article.Length > 500)
    {
        article = article.Substring(0, 500) + "...";
    }
```

However, when I execute the View, error:

```
exception: System.NullReferenceException: The reference of the object is not defined 
to an instance of the object.
```

If I do `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.article1)` alone, I get the article OK, but I want to do business logic beforehand.

What' s wrong with it ?

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning an `IEnumerable<Article>` to your model?  Also, are you sure each element of your enumerable is not null? `item.article` could be the source error if you have null elements.

Comment: hi, when I am doing @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.article1) in the foreach , I have the string result, that' s mean that' s not null no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off in your View, **triple check** to make sure that you are using your ViewModel correctly.

Something like this should be at the top of your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AJA.Models.DB.Article>
```

Set a breakpoint in your controller and use F10 to drill down all the way to your View, you will be able to inspect the objects in your View's foreach loop.

Somewhere along the line an object is null where you expect it to have something. Figure out what that object is.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var article = item.article1; //article1 may be null. Check it!
    if (article.Length > 500)
    {
        article = article.Substring(0, 500) + "...";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, very good sugestion, setting up the break point in the Controller ( and not the view :), and was able to see where the problem is coming from: one of the many fields is empty, thanks a lot to all of you.